# How to kill Find/Replace popup of CKEditor dynamically through JS

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to kill/destroy the Find/Replace popup instance of ckeditor through my code ie piece of code that is called when one clicks the close button of the popup

Comment: I too looking for this hack.. anyone ??